# iTunes connect flooding with IAP test apps

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I try to make IAP but for now with no luck. So I starting with different tutorials so I got my iTunes connect flooded with test apps.

If there is any possibility to test IAP without flooding iTunes connect with test apps ?

As I found out there is no chance to delete it if I do not even try finish them?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to test the In-App Purchase is using Itunes Connect where you can define one ore more dummy user to simulate and test the purchase process for your App

Comment: but you can't add an app to another user, right? You add it to your Apple ID, so afterwards you will get all your test apps and working apps in one place and you can't clean it. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You can test the In-App purchase in all your devices used for development. In iTunesConnect you have to define more dummy users. In your device you have to change the iTunesStore Apple ID every time with the dummy Apple ID set in iTunes Connect. You can change it when you want

Comment: If I used to make test apps from 5 different tutorials about IAP so all the 5 apps would be in iTunes connect, right? Or I can somehow get rid off this test apps by adding them into fake apple ID or not? Or anyway all the test apps will be at the real Apple ID?

Comment: You should use fake apple ID because if you have defined a cost in your App, you shouldn't pay for you test! You can manage all fake apple id for your test

Comment: Yes I do understand it. But how can I log in to iTunes connect with fake app ID or I should use fake app ID just inside of it?

Comment: From your device open Settings->AppStore and iTunes Store , tap on your current Apple ID then exit and put the fake Apple ID set for testing. At the end of your test , don't forget to restore your correct apple ID :-)

Comment: I think we are talking about different things. I know that I need to exit but I'm asking about log in to iTunes connect with origin or fake apple id that is it! Because my origin Apple ID has several test apps that I can't delete from iTunes connect

Comment: You can use only One Apple ID for your App to login in iTunesConnect and you can define more fake AppleID to test your In-App Purchase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91486/discussion-between-wm-p1us-and-lorenzo).